# Structuremap and generic types

Tags: c#, generics, structuremap

I have a situation which seems a bit different from others I've seen.  For clarrification, this isn't the normal question eg; something like IAClass maps to AClass etc - that involves using basically a single concrete classes per interface.

This involves having a single generic class, but I want to be able to load ALL possible usages of it.

Eg - the main class is of

```
public class MyClass<TDomainObject> : IMyClass<TDomainObject> 
     where TDomainObject : DomainObject
```

So example usages would be

```
IMyClass<Person> p = new MyClass<Person>;
IMyClass<Employer> p = new MyClass<Employer>;
```

I.e. for all DomainObjects I would like to be able to load a MyClass<> for.  So you can see I don't use a specific class for each declaration, they all use the same one.

How would I get this loaded into StructureMap?

Answer (score 3):

That's actually the more straightforward use of generics.

```
For(typeof(IMyClass<>)).Use(typeof(MyClass<>))
```

If you are using an older version of Structuremap, substitute the more verbose `ForRequestType` and `TheDefaultIsConcreteType`.

Comment: That's a really useful tip. I had no clue StructureMap could handle generics this way.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found out that you can use the auto register feature on Structuremap 2.5+ with generics over conventions, just like you could do with non-generics.

Just create your container like:

```
return new Container(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(y =>
            {
                y.TheCallingAssembly();
                y.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IMyClass<>));
                y.WithDefaultConventions();
            });
        });
```