# StructureMap auto-registration for interface with more than 1 generic type

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am looking for a convention-based way to replace the following line in my StructureMap registry:

```
this.For<IMyFactory<ItemList, int>>().Use(x => x.GetInstance<GenericMyFactory<ItemList, int>>());
```

**Clarification**

What I am after is a way to auto-register IMyFactory in a way that a concrete instance will be created with the same types in the same order as the interface declaration. The way I have declared above works for ItemList / int combination only - what I want is a way to do it with any combination of types.

I found this method on other SO posts, which seems to work great when there is only 1 type to be supplied, but I can't seem to find one that will work when more than 1 type is generic. The following gives a compile error in my case.

```
this.Scan(x =>
{
    x.TheCallingAssembly();
    x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IMyFactory<>));
    x.WithDefaultConventions();
});
```

Sources:

[StructureMap Auto registration for generic types using Scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516892/structuremap-auto-registration-for-generic-types-using-scan)

[Structuremap and generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644941/structuremap-and-generic-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register open generic types in StructureMap as follows:

```
For(typeof(IMyFactory<,>)).Use(typeof(GenericMyFactory<,>)));
```

Comment: Why would you like to scan? There is only one type to map.